# debugging code in python

Tags: python, debugging

I am writing some code to do this:
fill an array with numbers from 0 to 9 and then put the ones smaller than 5 at the end of it. My code is this:

```
    print ("give n: ")
    n = int(input())
    a = []
    for i in range(n):
        num = 0
        print ("give a number from 0 to 9 ")
        num = int(input())
        while (num > 9 and num < 0):
            print ("only from 0 to 9")
            num = int(input())
        a.append(num)
    tmp = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if (a[i]<5):
            tmp = a[i]
            a[i] = a[i+1]
            a[i+1] = tmp
    for i in range(n):
        print a[i]
```

My problem is that when i run it, the loop that checks if a number is from 0 to 9 is ignored if i give anything else and it passes it to the array and that it gives me an error on line 16 (a[i] = a[i+1]). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: name a number that is both greater than nine and less than zero.

Comment: Not related, but you don't need a temp variable to swap in Python; you can just do `a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i]`. Note also though that this won't really sort your list as you want.

Comment: `while (num < 9 and num > 0):`

Comment: @Milind Party crasher.

Comment: @Milind, that will loop for numbers between 0 and 9, and not loop for everything else, which is the opposite of the desired behavior.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For debugging in Python. 
Add `import pdb` and then put `pdb.set_trace()` where you want the debugger to break.

Answer (score -1):

There is debugger for python:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html
maybe useful to learn it right at the beginning.